# Psycopg2 connect_timeout not working in WSGI application

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, psycopg2, wsgi

I work on WSGI application (Simple HTTP RPC API) created using spyne library that runs on apache2 server. It uses psycopg2 library to handle database connections.

Everything works fine, but problem occurs when connection to database server is broken or server is not reachable through the network. When request is sent it hangs for 120 seconds (seems to be Unix socket timeout by default) a then psycopg2 **OperationalError** exception is raised.

**DB Connect part with connect_timeout:**

```
        try:
            connection_string = 'dbname=%s user=%s host=%s password=%s connect_timeout=5' % (db_name, db_user, server_ip, '')
            cx = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
        except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
            log.error('Unable to connect to the database at %s, %s' % (server_ip, e))
```

I have tried to use this part of code in other script and it worked as expected, after 5 seconds it raised **OperationalError** exception, but when I run the same code in WSGI application on apache2 this does not work.

I have tried to set **'socket-timeout=5'** for **WSGIDaemonProcess** and after this it hangs only for 5 seconds but it returns HTTP Code 504 to client instead of psycopg2 exception. I don't know why it ignores psycop2.connect timeout in WSGI application.

Does anybody know, what could be wrong, please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no Python expert, but I'm pretty sure if you're using `psycopg2.extensions.set_wait_callback` then you're using [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html)'s PQConnectPolling mechanism which ignores the `connect_timeout` parameter.

Not sure if there's a better way, but you can implement your own callback using [this](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/2_8_2/lib/extras.py#L746) as a template and pass a timeout to the `select.select` method